# How do I trigger a reload in an NSFetchedResultsController without changing the fetched object?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my iPhone app, I have an NSFetchedResultsController showing User objects in a UITableView. The User Objects have 0-many Log objects. A summary of the Log objects are shown together with their User object in the UITableView.

My app uses a tab bar, so user input in the logging tab require that the user tab's NSFetchedResultsController is triggered to reload.

So far I do it by writing to the User object:

```
log.user = nil;
log.user = [User current]; // Same as before. Just triggering a reload.
NSError *error = nil;
[myManagedObjectContext save:&error];
```

This works fine, but seems a bit like a hack.

Is there a better way to do this? Like specifying that changes in the Log object should propagate to the User object too?

Answer (score 2):

```
[myFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

But why would you want to do this?  It should only reload when there is new data for it to fetch.  If there is new data then a save of the `NSManagedObjectContext` is the right action.

What is your underlying goal?

Comment: There *is* new data available in the Log objects. The Log objects are summarized together with the User object in the user screen.

However, updating the Log object alone won't trigger a refresh of the fetched User object.

Comment: In that case if you are in the relevant view controller a call to `-reloadData` would be sufficient, if not then I would have the relevant view controller listen for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and refresh the table (or even narrow it down to specific cells) as needed.  Your initial solution feels risky.